# Where do I put my templates folder in a Flask app?

Tags: python, templates, flask, directory

I'm trying to use `render_template` in my Flask app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World", 200

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form["username"] != "admin" or request.form["password"] != "admin":
            error = "Invalid credentials. Please try again!"
        else:
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template("login.html", error=error)


app.run(debug=True)
```

I think that my app can't see `welcome.html` (and the templates folder) because I always get a "Internal Server Error" and no HTML page.

In a single folder, I have `app.py` the static folder and the templates folder (with the HTML file).

What's wrong here?

Comment: Remove the `/` just use `welcome.html`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but got the same server error.

Comment: Do `app.run(debug=True)` and check for error. A complete traceback would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your python script have all the necessary bits of a minimal Flask application?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template("/welcome.html")

if name== "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What do you mean with "bits"? 

The difference between my and your app is that you use name == "__main__"
I just wrote app.run()

Comment: You had not included most of your code at the time I wrote the above response, so it wasn't clear if it was in your script. By bits I just meant pieces/lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need a `/` in the name of the template.

<sup>(i.e. `'welcome.html'`, not `'/welcome.html'`).</sup>

See the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates) for render_template.

Answer (score 0):

It works with or without the slash.

Can you share the folder structure, and the script that you are executing (such as a **init.py**)

try looking at [this](https://github.com/Siddhartha90/Webpage/blob/master/app/views.py) (it's my repo for my webpage), to see if you might have missed something..

Answer (score 0):

By default, you'd need the templates to go on a folder called 'templates', all lowercase.

So, if your app is called app.py, and inside it you do render_template("welcome.html"), you'd need to have a file called welcome.html inside a templates folder at the same level as your app.py

app.py
templates
welcome.html